Image dection model doesn't work in Shiny Python app
I want to create a Shiny Python app without success for image detection. But the functions in ui don't work. My example is:
# Run in Jupyter notebook inside a conda environment where:
# pip install ultralytics
# pip install shiny

import shiny
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import torch
from torchvision.transforms import functional as F
import ultralytics as yolo

# Load the model
def load_model():
    model = yolo.YOLO("https://github.com/ultralytics/assets/releases/download/v0.0.0/yolov8n.pt")
    return model
  
model = load_model()

# Define the UI
ui = fluidPage(
    # App title
    titlePanel("Hello YOLOv8!"),
    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions
    sidebarLayout(
        # Sidebar panel for inputs
        sidebarPanel(
            # Input: File upload
            fileInput("image_path", label = "Input a JPEG image")
        ),
        # Main panel for displaying outputs
        mainPanel(
            # Output: Text
            textOutput(outputId = "prediction"),
            # Output: Plot
            plotOutput(outputId = "image")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to make predictions
def server(input, output):
    @input.on_change('image_path')
    def update_image(change):
        if change.new:
            # Convert uploaded image to a numpy array
            img = Image.open(change.new)
            img = np.array(img)

            # Preprocess image
            img = F.to_tensor(F.resize(img, (416, 416))).unsqueeze(0)

            # Use the loaded model to make predictions
            prediction = model(img)

            # Convert prediction to text
            output.prediction.value = "The predicted class is {}".format(prediction)

            # Display image
            output.image.data = img

# Create Shiny app
app = shiny.Shiny(ui = ui, server = server)

# Run the app
app.run_server()

# NameError: name 'fluidPage' is not defined


Please, any help with it?
